# How can I override methods notifyDataSetChanged, notifyItemChanged ... of RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As the title.
I'm writing a custom RecyclerView which supports multi select mode. And I need tracking selected/unselected state of each item. So after data size of recyclerView has changed. I want to update size of my tracking state list.
But I don't know where to override methods : notifyDataSetChanged, notifyItemChagned ....

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 20):

As the previous answer already correctly stated. You can't as those methods are **final**.

I came into the same situation when implementing the [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter)

The only solution I came up with is to name those methods slightly different. `notifyDataSetChanged` -> `notifyAdapterDataSetChanged`
https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.java#L1354

```
public void notifyAdapterDataSetChanged() {
    //... your custom logic
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For the library it was quite important to improve the documentation regarding this point, but it is the only solution as of now.

Answer (score 8):

You can't because it's `final` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`  see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())

You can `override` using `BaseAdapter` with `ListView`

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Register the adapter as the RecyclerView.Adapter's observer.

```
yourRecyclerView.getAdapter().registerAdapterDataObserver(new AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because ***you can't override final methods***.

Comment: This is a correct answer but you have to explain more and providing solutions to the OP. For example, wrapping the class or overriding animation, in case OP just wanted to change animation when `notifyItemInserted()`.